Did Adobe Change this past year? InDesign is exporting different grayscale values
We have a process for producing PDFs that we've used for years. We create an InDesign file with color elements - then we export using sGray output conversion to make a grayscale PDF for printing in B&W (we are not doing high-level graphics; charts and figures don't really care about exact color conversion).
The printer would then print that grayscale PDF using a predetermined dark blue pantone. All fine and good - that has been working for a decade or so.
This past year the conversion started producing a much lighter grayscale than previously. There is one particularly element that has a K value of 63% in the old B&W PDF. Over the past year the % gray has jumped around a lot between 63, 53 and 51%. We originally thought a few of the producers/workflows had a bad export profiles, but EVERYONE has the same profiles and now produces 51%.
We have no clue what changed or why. We are flummoxed and can't seem to figure out how to fix it. Best I've been able to do is change our export to do Dot20 instead (which gives a darker gray at 61%).
Can anyone give us a clue as to what may have changed. Did Adobe change how it processes color spaces or something with an update in the last year?
Note: we're using InDesign 2023 (18.5)

Oh boy, so honestly glad I'm not doing print any more :)))
